# Can a sentence contain both present participle and past participle?

Tags: tense, participles

A poem was written by David to explain the nature of love. And this poem attracted me. Can I write this?

> The poem written by David explaining love attracted me.

Let's imagine a poem has been written on a signboard in a park, and this poem explains the nature of love. Can I write this?

> The poem written on the signboard in this park explaining love attracted me.

Comment: How have you placed present participle after 'David' in the first sentence? It means that the task of explaining was done by David, not by poem. It is also true for second sentence. It seems that the nature of love was explained by park, not by poem.

Comment: those are both past participles so I can't answer that. (Written and attracted are both past participles.)

Comment: @NazmulHassan Not necessarily; postposited adjectivals like these participle clauses can be 'stacked' just like preposited attributive adjectives.

Comment: @SamHarrington No: *written* is a past participle, *explaining* is a present participle, and *attracted* is a past-tense finite verb.

Comment: Oh ok I just got confused sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier explained with a sentence diagram.

"The poem written by David explaining love" is a noun phrase that acts as the subject of the sentence.

This phrase is made up of a noun phrase and a participle clause: "The poem written by David" + "explaining love"

This noun phrase is in turn made up of "The poem" and the adjectival phrase "written by David".

This is perfectly grammatical, but this kind of construction is considered bad form because it makes the sentence harder to read. It can be 'fixed up' to make it more readable: "The poem explaining love, written by David, attracted me." The change in order is because "the poem" and "David" are both capable of "explaining", so it's ambiguous. It's clear that "the poem" and not "love" was "written". The parenthetical commas break up the sentence so it's easier to parse.

Answer (score 1):

These sentences are entirely proper, although as Nazmul Hassan suggests you would do better to rephrase them so it is clearer what the *explaining* clause modifies.

Don't be misled by the traditional names ***present*** participle and ***past*** participle.  Participles **don't have tense**; the clauses they head "borrow" their tenses from the surrounding context. You would do better to think of these as *active* and *passive participles* or as *perfect* and *progressive* participles.